# Copy a bit matrix from bitmap image in ANDROID programming

Tags: android, matrix, bitmap

I am developing an android app that helps user to copy a part of a bitmap by sketching or drawing. I mean the the user will draw some shapes on a Canvas that has the bitmap as background and then i have the points that are colored as a bitmap (bit matrix/ 2D bit array). Until here every hitng sounds good.

Now the problem is how can i copy the part of the image that has a corresponding true bit in the matrix?

### Added explanation

1) Main Image:

[image: Image be fore any process]

2) Image as canvas background:

[image: Image as canvas background]

3) Some paintings on canvas:

[image: User paints on canvas]

4) Bit matrix representation of painted area:

[image: Bit matrix]

5) Expected Output:

[image: Where is painted is outputted]

Comment: What should be present where the bits are UNset? What default value I mean.

Comment: @PaulStelian , They will be transparent. Assume that the true bits will be cut from the image!

Comment: Then how would you represent that transparency?

What kind of output do you have? PNG?

Comment: @PaulStelian , I think the best extension would be PNG! any idea? but i think it does not mention now. I think i should think about that when saving! am i true?

Comment: PNG has its own transparancy, to think of. That's why I suggested it. But you need the format.

Comment: For displaying on screen, I doubt you can do transparency anyways.

Comment: @PaulStelian , so what the solution? first for showing on screen and second for keeping them in memory.

Comment: I have no particular solution for showing on screen but I would make a simplifying assumption that you'd know a background color for the target image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like this. The example uses a `Bitmap` as the source and another `Bitmap` as the filter matrix. The filter bitmap has a transparent background and so has the filtered bitmap:

```
public Bitmap doFilter(Bitmap source, Bitmap filter) {
    Bitmap filtered = Bitmap.createBitmap(source.getWidth(), source.getHeight(), source.getConfig());

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(filtered);

    canvas.drawBitmap(source, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(filter, 0, 0, paint);

    return filtered;
}
```

For example, with this source:

[image]

And this filter:

[image]

You get this filtered image:

[image]

Comment: I wish i could give the bounty both to you and Debu! both answers are great. I am going to test them but i think although Debu's answer is more detailed, antonio's would be better at all.

Comment: I've tested you code and it was just worked as best. thanks. TG.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your given explanations I made the following a Sample project and the code is given below -

```
public class ActivityImage extends AppCompatActivity{
Button grab;
CustomImageView iv_custom;
ImageView iv_later;
Bitmap bitmapBG,bitmapOrg;
int iMin,jMin,iMax,jMax;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.so_particular_img_section);
    iv_custom = (CustomImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_custom);
    iv_custom.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    iv_later = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iv_later);
    grab = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_grab);
    grab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            iv_custom.buildDrawingCache();
            bitmapBG = iv_custom.getDrawingCache();
            getSelectedRegionOnly();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * this method will return the whole image But only the selected region is highlighted and the rest section is simply white
 */
private void getSelectedRegionWithBG(){
    int[] mainImageArray = iv_custom.getImagePixels();
    int[] bgImageArray = new int[bitmapBG.getWidth() * bitmapBG.getHeight()];
    int[] finalImageArray = new int[bitmapBG.getWidth() * bitmapBG.getHeight()];
    bitmapBG.getPixels(bgImageArray,0,bitmapBG.getWidth(), 0, 0, bitmapBG.getWidth(), bitmapBG.getHeight());

    if(mainImageArray.length == bgImageArray.length){
        for(int i = 0; i < (bitmapBG.getWidth() * bitmapBG.getHeight());i++){
            if(mainImageArray[i] == bgImageArray[i]){
                finalImageArray[i] = Color.WHITE;
            }else{
                finalImageArray[i] = mainImageArray[i];
            }
        }

        Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapBG.getWidth(), bitmapBG.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // Set the pixels
        finalBitmap.setPixels(finalImageArray, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight());
        iv_later.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(ActivityImage.this,"Array length are not same",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}

/**
 * This method will select only the selected region from the main image and create the bitmap
 */
private void getSelectedRegionOnly(){
    generateBounds();
    int count = 0;
    int[] finalImageArray = new int[(1+iMax - iMin) * (1+jMax - jMin)];
    Bitmap finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap((1+jMax - jMin), (1+iMax - iMin), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        for(int i = iMin; i <= iMax; i++){
            for(int j = jMin; j <= jMax; j++){
                if(bitmapBG.getPixel(j,i) != bitmapOrg.getPixel(j,i)) {
                    finalImageArray[count] = bitmapOrg.getPixel(j, i);
                }else {
                    finalImageArray[count] = Color.WHITE;
                }
                count++;
            }
        }
        // Set the pixels
        finalBitmap.setPixels(finalImageArray, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), 0, 0, finalBitmap.getWidth(), finalBitmap.getHeight());
        iv_later.setImageBitmap(finalBitmap);

}

/**
 * generates the bound of the coloured region
 */
private void generateBounds(){
    bitmapOrg = iv_custom.getMainBitmap();
    iMax = jMax = 0;
    iMin = jMin = bitmapBG.getWidth() * bitmapBG.getHeight();
    for(int i = 0; i < bitmapBG.getHeight(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < bitmapBG.getWidth(); j++){
            if(bitmapBG.getPixel(j,i) != bitmapOrg.getPixel(j,i)){
                if(iMin > i){
                    iMin = i;
                }
                if(jMin > j){
                    jMin = j;
                }
                if(iMax < i){
                    iMax = i;
                }
                if(jMax < j){
                    jMax = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

The layout file -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="GRAB IMAGE"
    android:id="@+id/btn_grab"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/demo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_above="@id/btn_grab"
    >
    <com.wandertails.stackovrflw.CustomImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv_custom"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/iv_later"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally the custom image View -

```
public class CustomImageView extends ImageView {
int width,height;
Bitmap sample;

Context con;
Paint paint=new Paint();
public CustomImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    con = context;
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    con = context;
}

public CustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    con = context;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    sample = createBackground(width,height,con);
    canvas.drawBitmap(sample,0,0,paint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(createForeground(width,height,con),0,0,paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.RED);
    //canvas.drawRect(400,400,600,600,paint);
    //canvas.drawCircle(400,400,200,paint);
}

public int[] getImagePixels(){
    int[] pixels = new int[sample.getWidth() * sample.getHeight()];
    sample.getPixels(pixels, 0, sample.getWidth(), 0, 0, sample.getWidth(), sample.getHeight());
    return pixels;
}

public Bitmap getMainBitmap(){
    return sample;
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

private Bitmap createBackground(int width, int height, Context con) {
    Bitmap logo = null;
    logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.sample);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(logo,width,height,true).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
}

private Bitmap createForeground(int width, int height, Context con) {
    Bitmap logo = null;
    logo = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(con.getResources(), R.drawable.sample1);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(logo,width,height,true).copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true);
}

}
```

Here are some of the screen shots that I acheive - 
[image: Here the green image is the pattern(like the yellow region of image 3 of yours) and the Horse image is the actual main image]

[image: Here the red colored shapes are patterns]

The code may not be that optimized, but I think it will serve your purpose.  Moreover,you can use any shape or design as mask(the region that needs to be selected),ask me if you need any explanation..

Comment: I wish i could give the bounty both to you and antonio! both answers are great. I am going to test them but i think although Debu's answer is more detailed, antonio's would be better at all.

Comment: Antonio's answer is obviously right if you need only masking, but I made this example so that you have the following benefits - 
1. You don't need any filter bitmap
2. In a custom scenario like user can select(ex. say user can touch and drag finger to select) any section the image, this code will work

Comment: 3. Finally say there is a 200 x 200 image and the user has selected 40 x 40 from say, right-top section, then using getSelectedRegionOnly() you can have a 40 x 40 bitmap of the selected section only. 
I don't need bounties, if my code solves your problem, thats my biggest reward

Comment: this sentence is great "if my code solves your problem, thats my biggest reward". your code is very good in its own way. but i will use the generated picture as layer for future works and i need the sizes to keep same as default. and i have to say that the bounties are just to thank your effort not the price of the work. Thanks a lot. TG.

Answer (score 0):

I would have three Bitmaps. The first is what you show as the background. The second would be where the user draws the mask and the third would be the result.

Show the background image and draw the mask Bitmap on top of that. Allow the user to draw on the mask. Once they're happy with the mask just iterate over the pixels and when you find one that's not empty you know that's a pixel that should be copied over. You will have the pixel position from your iteration so you can just read at that location from the background Bitmap and write that value into the result Bitmap.

Comment: You are just returning my explanations back to myself. I need some working code which results non square picture out.